# Why is math.MaxInt64 inferred as int32?

Tags: go

Trying to cross-compile for GOARCH 386:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    i := math.MaxInt64
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

build:

```sh
env GOARCH=386 go run main.go
```

output:

```
# command-line-arguments
./sample.go:9:4: constant 9223372036854775807 overflows int
```

why does var `i` is inferred as int32 and not int64? Is this a well-known bug or specification of go lang?

Comment: I mean,  math.MaxInt64 is obviously int64 type for me but go compiler seems it doesn't agree with me.

Comment: `int` on 386 is int32 and integer constants become `int`s. All is fine, everything is working according to the spec. What exactly is your question? Which part of the spec is unclear? It does not matter what you think math.MaxInt64 to be or not to be. The relevant authority is the language spec.

Comment: Yes, but I have not declared the variable with explicit type and I thought the compiler should infer the variable with the assigned value.

Comment: No, `math.MaxInt64` is not an `int64`, obvious or otherwise. It's an [untyped numerical constant](https://blog.golang.org/constants). You can see this [for yourself](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#pkg-constants).

Comment: "I thought the compiler should infer the variable with the assigned value" It does. But constants work a bit different. Read https://blog.golang.org/constants

Comment: So, this is called untyped numeric constant! It seems now I understand! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`math.MaxInt64` is [defined](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#pkg-constants) like so:

```
const (
    MaxInt64  = 1<<63 - 1
)
```

From https://blog.golang.org/constants:

> The concept of untyped constants in Go means that all the numeric
>   constants, whether integer, floating-point, complex, or even character
>   values, live in a kind of unified space. It's when we bring them to
>   the computational world of variables, assignments, and operations that
>   the actual types matter.

By forcing your compilation to a 32-bit architecture, you are coercing the go default `int` type for numbers to an explicit `int32` - whereas on most modern CPUs `int` is implicitly an `int64`.

---

Incidentally, if you explicitly use the type `int64` (instead of the inferred `int` type):

```
var i int64
i = math.MaxInt64
```

while this may *"compile"* for 32-bit architecture, it will **not** run:

```
GOARCH=386 go build -o too_big && ./too_big

./too_big: Bad CPU type in executable
```